# Is there a possibility to use abstract Cubits with generic states?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, bloc, flutter-bloc

I got stuck on the problem of using a generic type as a Cubit state. The problem is the immutability of Cubit states in combination with the inability to call `copyWith` for a generic type. A similar implementation based on ChangeNotifier does not cause problems, since we can mutate the returned state.

For example, I have created a basic Cubit having generic state, which I plan to extend. Then I implementing generic type of cubit state by adding a field and copyWith() to it.

```
abstract class BasePageCubit<TParams extends BasePageParams>
    extends Cubit<TParams> {
  BasePageCubit({
    required TParams initialState,
  }) : super(initialState);

  @mustCallSuper
  void initialise() {
    emit(state);
  }

  @protected
  void markLoaded() {
    emit(
      **state.copyWith(isLoading: false)**,
    );
  }
}


@CopyWith()
class DataParams<TData> extends BasePageParams {
  TData data;

  DataParams({
    required this.data,
    super.isLoading = true,
    super.pageError,
  });
}
```

Obviously, I can't use `state.copyWith(isLoading: false)` in BasePageCubit, but I don't see any other ways to implement expandeble logic working with the Cubit inherited from BasePageCubit. In general, I need universal copyWith() regardless of available class fields. Is this a fundamental limitation of the Dart type system, or are there any workarounds? Maybe I misunderstand Bloc pattern with inheritance?